# How might I modify this recipe for home-made vegan meat alternative so that it tastes like SPAM?

Tags: meat-substitutes

I slightly edited a recipe from ***Meriel Armitage***.

Can you edit the recipe further to create faux ham?

If we omit the soy-sauce, what additional spices, salt, and/or vegetable juices can we add to the recipe to make it taste like canned ham or spiced ham?

I was hoping beet juice might make it pink, but I will let you decide.

Perhaps something vegan fatty and mostly solid at room temperature mixed into it?

## Vegan Meat

Also known as fake-meat or faux-meat.

### Ingredients

> - strong gluten flour --- a cup and a half
>   > *  water -- unknown quantity of water
>   > *  soy sauce -- unknown quantity of soy sauce
>   > *  nutritional yeast with some B12 vitamins -- unknown quantity
>   > *  smoked paprika -- unknown quantity
>
> For the marinade:
>
> - one of the following
>
>   - 2 teaspoons dried chili flakes
>   - 1 whole red chili, stemmed and finely chopped
> - all of the following:
>
>   - 3 garlic cloves, minced
>   - 2-3 limes, juiced
>   - 1 bunch cilantro, finely chopped (including stems)
>   - 1 red onion, finely chopped
>   - 2 tablespoons vegetable oil

### Directions

> #### Pour the Ingredients into a Bowl
>
> > Put the following in an electric mixer:
> >
> > - gluten flour
> > - soy sauce
> > - nutritional yeast
> > - paprika
>
> Add small amounts of water as time progresses.
>
> #### Mix the Dough Thoroughly
>
> The dough should be extremely firm to the touch. Don’t add too much water. It should be closer to a solid than a liquid.
>
> Really stretch the gluten in exactly the same way as making bread or making pizza dough.
>
> #### Boil the Vegan Meat
>
> > In order to get a firm texture, you would boil the vegan meat. I would recommend boiling it quite rapidly for 45 to 60 minutes. You will notice that it will it will shrink in size and toughen up a bit.
>
> Slice the Vegan Meat
>
> cut really really thin slices. It should visually resemble Greek gyros.
>
> Marinate the vegan meat:
>
> In a large bowl, mix the vegan meat with the chili, garlic, lime juice, beer, cilantro, and red onion to coat. Cover, then refrigerate for at least 1 hour and up to 24 hours.

Comment: your question may be a better fit at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola Why? Questions about vegan cooking are on-topic here, and this site has more need of questions than the much larger Cooking.SE.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I did not say that it is off topic here ... the cooking site may have more expertise when it comes to adjusting taste of food, so the question may have a better chance of getting a good answer there

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon start by finding out what are the ingredients in SPAM and how it is made ... then determine the vegan equivalents of the ingredients ... try to follow the same process in manufacturing, for example, if the meat is coarse ground, then try coarse grinding the seitan ... etc

Comment: @jsotola your last comment seems to be an answer to the question rather than a comment :)

Comment: I have no idea what SPAM tastes like, but this recipe for vegan baked seitan ham looks really, really good https://thecheekychickpea.com/vegan-ham/